DeepDiff regex_exclude_paths filters out everything, not just the path I want
I'm using DeepDiff with exclude_regex_paths="['seqid']" to exclude certain fields, but I'm noticing that everything, not just the fields I want to exclude are excluded. Real differences, outside the path to be excluded, aren't being reported.
Here's my code:
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

data1 = {
    "record1": {"seqid": "ABC123", "value": 1},
    "record2": {"seqid": "DEF456", "value": 2}
}

data2 = {
    "record1": {"seqid": "XYZ789", "value": 3},  # value changed from 1 to 3
    "record2": {"seqid": "UVW321", "value": 4}   # value changed from 2 to 4
}

diff = DeepDiff(data1, data2, exclude_regex_paths="['seqid']")
print(diff) # {} - Empty output, but value differences should be shown

I expected this to exclude only the 'seqid' differences while still showing the value differences, but I'm getting an empty diff. What am I doing wrong? I'm on DeepDiff version 8.0.1.
The documentation unfortunately doesn't really define the path syntax to use.
I found a related, inverse question: DeepDiff exclude_paths regex not filtering out paths

I figured out the issue: unescaped square brackets were interpreted as defining a character set that matches any single character that is either ' or s or e or q or i or d. And all paths that are matched by DeepDiff contain at least two ' - so everything is excluded.
The fix is to escape special regex characters, in this case the square brackets: exclude_regex_paths="\['seqid'\]". This works correctly:
print(DeepDiff(data1, data2, exclude_regex_paths="\['seqid'\]"))
# {'values_changed': {"root['record1']['value']": {'new_value': 3, 'old_value': 1}, "root['record2']['value']": {'new_value': 4, 'old_value': 2}}}

A more careful but verbose solution might be:
diff = DeepDiff(
    data1, 
    data2, 
    exclude_regex_paths=r"root\[.*?\]\['seqid'\]$"
)

This pattern:

Properly escapes brackets to match them literally
Uses .*? for non-greedy matching between parts
Uses $ to ensure we only match 'seqid' at the end of a path

